# Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.5.0.0

Tags: maven, ambari

`I have been trying to install ambari using tarball , but got stuck at metrics timeline service.`

`I have tried updating the pom.xml`
`apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics`
`replace in pom.xml  %s/0-315/1-1/g`

`apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice`

`pom.xml`

`

```
<!-- Needed for generating FindBugs warnings using parent pom -->

<!--<yarn.basedir>${project.parent.parent.basedir}</yarn.basedir>-->
<protobuf.version>2.5.0</protobuf.version>
<hadoop.version>3.1.1.3.1.4.1-1</hadoop.version>
<phoenix.version>5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1</phoenix.version>
<hbase.version>2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1</hbase.version>
```

`

`But still getting the error as below`

> Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-timelineservice: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.5.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1 -> org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:jar:2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1 -> org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:jar:2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1 -> org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2 -> org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish:javax.el:pom:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [hwx-public (http://repo.hortonworks.com/nexus/content/groups/public/, default, releases+snapshots), apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots)] -> [Help 1]

Can Anyone Please help me out .

Comment: You have http repos in your settings/pom configuration which are not allowed... use https instead and use central instead of repository.apache.org...

Comment: @khmarbaise could you please point out the changes to be done . That would be helpful .

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html#how-to-fix-when-i-get-a-http-repository-blocked